# Parsing json with retrofit2 gson-converter, with fields of another name

Tags: java, android, retrofit, gson

I am trying to parse a json object which has field named "long", long is a keyword in java so I cannot use simple gson examples provided in retrofit page.

Should I create a custom converter or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `@SerializedName`. This is a `Gson` annotation which tells it how to serialize and deserialize the objects to json and vice-versa. You could have the following model:

```
public class YourModel {
   @SerializedName("long")
   @Expose
   private String theNameYouWantForYourVariable;
}
```

Note that I'm assuming it's a `String`, but you can use whatever data type you want and need. The `@Expose` annotation is not necessary, but recommended.

The key thing here is to notice the `SerializedName` annotation that takes the json's field name. Here's the [javadoc](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html)